# PHP - parse large CSV into array of arrays - memory size exhausted

Tags: php, parsing, csv, memory-leaks

I would like to ask for help with this task:
I have large CSV: 680 columns x 1300 rows and I need to parse it **by columns** (I need to have array of arrays of column values).

I use this code for this:

```
$input = "data/input.csv";

    if (($handle = fopen($input, "r")) !== false) {
        $filesize = filesize($input);
        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, $filesize, "$")) !== false) {
            for ($i = 0; $i < count($data); $i++) {
                $this->columns[$i][] = $data[$i];
            }
        }
        fclose($handle);
```

Problem is, that I get this error

*Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 16384 bytes) in /www/classes/Analyser.php on line 72*

line 72 is **$this->columns[$i][] = $data[$i];**

My hosting does not allow me to increase the memory limit. Is there a way to write the code efficiently, so there is no need for so much memory, or is it just problem of such large CSV?

Thanks everyone.

Comment: Your problem is trying to read a large csv file into memory. If you want to parse it column by column rather than row by row, then you may need to read the csv several times, once for each column, building an array of only that column, process it, then rewind and repeat for the next column

Comment: Yes, I understand. Please could You edit my code for read the csv once for each column, process it and read again? I am trying, but it does not work. Thank You very much

Answer (score 0):

```
function analyze_column($column) {
    // do your work here
    return $the_results;
}

$a = 0;
$results = array();

while ($a < COUNT_OF_COLUMNS) {
    $column = Array();
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, $filesize, "$")) !== false) {
        array_push($column,$data[$a]);
    }

    $results[] = analyze_column($column);

    $a++;
}
```

Comment: Still the same, once the $column is cleared, I canť push to it.

Comment: Is there an error? You might need to provide the rest of your code to get an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [PHP Generators](https://www.php.net/manual/language.generators.overview.php). They are designed to solve this issue.