# PHP - parse CSV column by columns

Tags: php, parsing, csv

I would like to ask for help with this task.
I have a large CSV and I wish to parse it column by column (and analyze every column somehow).
My idea is like this, but it does not work (once the array is unset, I canť push to it anymore):

```
$a = 0;
    while ($a < COUNT_OF_COLUMNS) {
        $column = Array();
        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, $filesize, "$")) !== false) {
            array_push($column,$data[$a]);
        }

        $a++;
    }
```

Any help would be appreciate
Thanks everyone

Comment: Can you combine this question with your previous one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34078183/php-parse-large-csv-into-array-of-arrays-memory-size-exhausted?rq=1 They're really the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Array of Arrays not being the answer, try this:

```
$a = 0;
$results = array();

while ($a < COUNT_OF_COLUMNS) {
    $column = Array();
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, $filesize, "$")) !== false) {
        array_push($column,$data[$a]);
    }

    $results[] = do_your_analysis_here($column);

    $a++;
}
```

Comment: I can't use array of arrays, the CSV is so large, that I get memory leak. I need to load one column, analyze it and throw it away.

Comment: In that case, you should just analyze the column after the inner `while{}` loop closes, before you `$a++`

Comment: Ok, and then what? I will still have array of arrays :(

Comment: You might also get good results from pushing your csv into a database, like sqlite, and doing the analysis there. Depends on what you're doing, but sometimes brute force isn't the answer.